# Unit testing a stream that returns a stream

Tags: testing, flutter, dart

I'm currently trying to unit test my BLoC Flutter code but I've got a failed test because of what I'll describe as a 'nested' stream.

Here is the test code:

```
test('fetch carbon events successfully', () async {
      final List<CarbonAction> actions = [];
      final List expected = [
        StateA(),
        StateB(),
        StateC()
      ];


      when(repo.getActions()).thenAnswer((_) => Stream.value(actions));

      expectLater(
        homeBloc.state,
        emitsInOrder(expected),
      );

      homeBloc.dispatch(FetchActionsEvent());
    });
```

It is failing with this error:

```
Expected: should do the following in order:
          • emit an event that StateA:<StateA>
          • emit an event that StateB:<StateB>
          • emit an event that StateC:<StateC>
  Actual: <Instance of 'BehaviorSubject<State>'>
   Which: emitted • StateA
                  • StateB
                  • StateC
            which didn't emit an event that StateC:<StateC>
```

I believe this is happening because StateC actually comes a stream that is emitted using `async*` and `yield*`. In my code all of this is working currently.

Comment: I would think that it is because you are not correctly overwriting the` hashcode` and `==` operator of StateC. Please show the code of the 3 states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that this is just a very unhelpful error message and it's that this was just the test failing to pass.

I'd make sure that all the fields of your objects match exactly, especially if you're using Equatable.